# 同名クラスをもつ複数のaタグを順番に繰り返し処理し、必要なデータをDBに保存したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, rubygems, nokogiri

**環境**

ruby 2.7.2
rails 6.1
macOS

**前提**

ポートフォリオ作成のため、現在自作アプリを実装しております。
その中で、DBに必要なデータを保存するため、Rubyのnokogiriでスクレイピングを行なっています。

**解決したいこと**

`<a class="flower-spot"`内のhref属性の値を取得し、その値をもとに`link_url`を作成して遷移を行い、遷移後のページから必要なデータをDBに保存。
それを同名クラスの数だけ繰り返したいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**試したこと**

nokogiriに関連する記事を調べ、下記コードを作成した所、必要なデータをDBに保存することはできました。
しかし、コードが冗長で見辛くなっているため、改善したいです。
詳しい方がいましたら是非アドバイスいただけると幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

**該当するソースコード**

`db/schema.rb`

```
create_table "spots", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "location", null: false
    t.text "feature", null: false
    t.string "image"
    t.string "url"
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "area_id"
    t.index ["area_id"], name: "index_spots_on_area_id"
  end
```

`app/models/scraping.rb`

```
class Scraping < ApplicationRecord
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'nokogiri'

  def self.spot_scrape
    base_url = 'https://loconavi.jp/'
    features_url = 'features/hananomeisho'
    url = "#{base_url}#{features_url}?flower=229"

    html = URI.open(url).read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
    # href属性値の取得(相対URL)
    # _[0]_として一番目のflower-spotクラスを対象
    href = doc.css('.flower-spot')[0]["href"]
    # 相対URLから絶対URLを作成
    link_url = "#{base_url}#{href}"

    html = URI.open(link_url).read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

    doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do | node |
      sleep 1
      # DBに取得したデータを保存
      Spot.create!(
        name: node.at_css('.block').inner_text,
        location: node.css('.t-cell')[2].inner_text,
        feature: node.at_css('.text').inner_text,
        image: node.at_css('img').attribute('src'),
        url: node.at_css('#information p a')["href"]
      )
    end

    html = URI.open(url).read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
    href = doc.css('.flower-spot')[1]["href"]
    link_url = "#{base_url}#{href}"

    html = URI.open(link_url).read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

    doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do | node |
      sleep 1
      Spot.create!(
        name: node.at_css('.block').inner_text,
        location: node.css('.t-cell')[2].inner_text,
        feature: node.at_css('.text').inner_text,
        image: node.at_css('img').attribute('src'),
        url: node.at_css('#information p a')["href"]
      )
    end

    html = URI.open(url).read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
    href = doc.css('.flower-spot')[2]["href"]
    link_url = "#{base_url}#{href}"

    html = URI.open(link_url).read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

    doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do | node |
      sleep 1
      Spot.create!(
        name: node.at_css('.block').inner_text,
        location: node.css('.t-cell')[2].inner_text,
        feature: node.at_css('.text').inner_text,
        image: node.at_css('img').attribute('src'),
        url: node.at_css('#information p a')["href"]
      )
      break
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

冗長というのは、次の行の

```
    href = doc.css('.flower-spot')[0]["href"]
```

`[0]` の部分が `0`, `1`, `2` と異なるだけで、他はまったく同じ処理が3回繰り返されているということだと思います。

`times` を使うと、

```
3.times do |i|
  # i の値が 0, 1, 2 と変化して繰り返す
end
```

のように書けるので、次のようにループにすることができます。

```
  3.times do |i|
    html = URI.open(url).read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
    href = doc.css('.flower-spot')[i]["href"]  # ここで 0, 1, 2 の代わりに i を使う
    link_url = "#{base_url}#{href}"

    html = URI.open(link_url).read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

    doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do | node |
      sleep 1
      Spot.create!(
        name: node.at_css('.block').inner_text,
        location: node.css('.t-cell')[2].inner_text,
        feature: node.at_css('.text').inner_text,
        image: node.at_css('img').attribute('src'),
        url: node.at_css('#information p a')["href"]
      )
    end
  end
```